# What's the probability that each shooter, A, B, C, respectively, will hit the target only once?

Tags: probability

Three shooters shoot at the same target. The probability for every shooter is $A, B, C$ respectively. What is the probability that the shooters will hit the target only once?

I know I can do something like:
$$P(X = 1) = P(A)P(B^c)P(C^c)+P(A^c)P(B)P(C^c)+P(A^c)P(B^c)P(C)$$

But is there any shorter way to solve this problems? .

Comment: "*Is there a shorter way*" For a problem exactly like this?  Not really, no.  This is already quite short and easy to understand.  Going to the case of four shooters to make the pattern clearer, you could I suppose reduce the total number of operations by saying it is $\Pr(A)\Pr(B^c)\Pr(C^c)\Pr(D^c) + \Pr(A^c)(\Pr(B)\Pr(C^c)\Pr(D^c)+\Pr(B^c)(\Pr(C)\Pr(D^c) +\Pr(C^c)(\Pr(D))))$

Comment: In doing so it reduces the total number of multiplications from $12$ to only $9$.  You get even more savings with larger numbers of shooters.  As an aside, do be careful of overloading a symbol.  Here, was $A$ the name of the first shooter?  Was $A$ the event the first shooter hit?  Was $A$ the probability that the first shooter hit?  All three of these being named $A$ is confusing.

Comment: Kind-of shorter: $P(A^c)P(B^c)P(C^c)(P(A)/P(A^c)+P(B)/P(B^c)+P(C)/P(C^c))$. Significantly shorter for even more people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you consider shorter. You can do it with five instead of six multiplications using [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)):

$$P(X=1)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-2P(A)P(B)-2P(A)P(C)-2P(B)P(C)+3P(A)P(B)P(C)\;.$$

(Multiplying by an integer doesn’t require a multiplication since you can replace it by the corresponding number of additions.)

Comment: $\Pr(X=1)\neq \Pr(X\geq 1)$

Comment: @JMoravitz: I don't understand your comment. Where does $\Pr(X\geq 1)$ appear in my answer?

Comment: The expansion of inclusion exclusion you have here is in reference to $\Pr(A\cup B\cup C)$.  The random variable $X$ here is counting the number of events $A,B,C$ which the specific outcome is an element of.  With respect to the random variable, we have $\Pr(A\cup B\cup C)=\Pr(X\geq 1)$ is the RHS of your expression above, which is unequal to the LHS.

Comment: Included in $\Pr(A\cup B\cup C)$ then is for example the sub-event of $A\cap B\cap C$ which corresponds to $X=3$ which should not have been counted if we were interested exclusively in $\Pr(X=1)$

Comment: @JMoravitz: Sorry, you're right, I don't know why I didn't see that the first time you wrote it :-) Somehow I thought I'd substracted out the multiple cases, but of course I'd only subtracted out their double-counting. I think the answer is correct now? But unfortunately even less useful that it already was...